# filter rows in pandas dataframe with specified interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe table with shape (104238, 88). I want to extract only rows with values either 1 or 0 (not boolean)

Dataframe_input

```
Index C1  C2  C3  C4.... C88
R1    200 0   20  40     1068
R2    0   0    0   0     1
R3    1   1    1   1     0
```

After subsetting, I want R2, R3 to be extracted. i.e all elements in entire row is either 0 or 1

I tried,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Dataframe.txt', sep='\t', index_col='Index')
df2 = df[[df.columns].all(axis=1) <2]
```

I get the error,

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'all'

What is the error here? Please help.

Thanks in advance,

AP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably with [df.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
df[df.isin([0,1]).all(1)]
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

```
print(df)

    C1  C2  C3  C4  C88
0   200 0   20  40  1068
1   0   0   0   0   1
2   1   1   1   1   0
```

Use the following code to select only rows with 0 and 1

```
df2 = df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: x.isin([1,0])).all(axis=1)]

print(df2)

    C1  C2  C3  C4  C88
1   0   0   0   0   1
2   1   1   1   1   0
```